# Bulk rename/delete on many wiki pages in trac, how?

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, bulk, bug-tracker

does trac web interface provide a way to delete, rename, etc. a lot of wiki pages as a whole, without having to do the tedious task one by one and manually? Something like a checkbox for each page, followed by a Delete button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update** use [bta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923367/bulk-rename-delete-on-many-wiki-pages-in-trac-how/5957922#5957922) instead of this.

There is no trac interface I am aware of, but you might be able to do this by manually editing the database. For example [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) is able to open the `db/trac.db` file and might be a little bit less tedious than manually using the trac interface. But make a backup before you try....

You have to edit the name field in the wiki table.

Comment: Almost unbelievable! Anyway, maybe a good idea for a Django app.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this through the [`trac-admin`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin) command-line utility.  Use the syntax

```
trac-admin /path/to/project/env wiki remove WikiPageName
```

to remove a wiki page.  You should be able to write a simple script that runs this command for every page in a list.  You can use the `wiki list` command to retrieve a list of all wiki pages, which might be useful if you are wanting to delete wiki pages whose names follow a particular pattern (also useful for deleting a page and all of its sub-pages).

Comment: +1, there is also a wiki rename command. See http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin